# C++ class/struct member offset as constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following construct in `main()` retrieves a class member's `offset` at runtime:

```cpp
struct Base
{
  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Cls : public virtual Base
{
  int a, b;
};



int main()
{
  int Cls::* ptr = &Cls::a;

  unsigned long offset = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&ptr);
}
```

The class layout is determined at compile time and doesn't change. So, it would be beneficial to make this a `constexpr`.

Unfortunately, the above assignment requires an lvalue.

How can I get the same result using a `constexpr`?

Comment: Are you looking for [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)?

Comment: You cast an `int Cls::**` to a `unsigned long*` and then dereference that. That's just UB.

Comment: Unfortunately no. `offsetof` doesn't work correctly with virtual base classes and other non-POD types.

Comment: @AvD: There's a reason for that, namely that "class layout is determined at compile time and doesn't change" is incorrect.  When virtual base classes are involved, subobject in-memory layout can be different for different most-derived class types.

Comment: It'd be interesting to hear what you need this for.  Perhaps there are alternative solutions that does _not_ involve undefined behavior.

Comment: The current PLC memory layout implementation uses `offsetof`, but GCC returns an error on virtual classes: `error G1D36D614: invalid access to non-static data member 'Entities::Entity::Id' in virtual base of NULL object` — I don't understand. AFAIK, the `&Class::Member` syntax' sole purpose is to get the offset of a class' member.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, it may be *different* for *different* derived types, yet given any type in the hierarchy, the offset is always fixed. There is no such thing like run-time evaluation of class layout.

Comment: @AxD: No, `&Class::Member` forms a pointer-to-member, which is not a simple offset.  Virtual base classes do cause run-time evaluation of layout, because the layout of base subobjects changes depending on the most-derived type.

Comment: I see. Let's settle it here. I received plenty of valuable information by @BenVoigt and @ user17732522.

Answer (score 3):

Your class is not standard-layout. There is no way to obtain an offset to a member of a non-standard-layout class without undefined behavior (and therefore certainly not in a compile-time context) that is guaranteed to be supported by the standard, although see `offsetof` below.

Your approach is definitively UB per standard, even in a standard-layout class. It relies on very specific implementation details, assuming it works in the first place. (I haven't tested it.)

Since C++17 use of the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro is conditionally-supported (also in a compile-time context) for non-standard-layout classes. If the compiler does not support this, then what you want to do is impossible (except maybe via other compiler extensions), however all current compilers I am aware of support this, even if they emit warnings:

```
constexpr auto offset = offsetof(Cls, a);
```

(Before C++17 it was technically UB although the same practical consideration as above applies.)

But beware that layout in derived classes is not guaranteed to be consistent with `virtual` bases.

Comment: *"Non-standard-layout and hence UB"* looks like a pure formality. AFAIK `offsetof` should always work (as long as you add a pragma to silence this warning).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I guess so, but e.g. Clang refuses to compile it with `-pedantic-errors`. The compiler needs to implement this with a built-in to make it work in a constant expression context, so I could image a compiler that simply doesn't bother implementing it fully (although I am not aware of any).

Comment: Mhm, Clang needs a pragma to stops complaining about this.

Comment: *"But beware that layout in derived classes is not guaranteed to be consistent with virtual bases."* – That isn't true. Memory layout of any class is determined at compile time. So the layout is fixed. Yet, different compilers may choose different sequence of base classes if a class is derived from multiple base classes. But even that is determined at compile time. There is not such thing like run-time evaluation of class layout.

Comment: FWIW, I created an issue for Microsoft MSVC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-Class::Member-operator-yields-wro/10231759

Comment: @AxD That's what I meant with "inconsistent". I did not mean a runtime decision, just that the relative offset of the base class and its members is not necessarily the same in derived classes. It doesn't matter for your concrete example in this question.

Comment: @AxD The purpose of member pointers is definitively not to give a byte offset to the member. That just happens to be a typical implementation. The issue is probably going to be closed as invalid.

Comment: The only thing that can give a byte offset of a member reliably is the `offsetof` macro which has to be implemented as a magic compiler built-in.

Answer (score -7):

Found the solution myself:

```cpp
template<class T> constexpr unsigned long Offset(T ptr)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&ptr);
}
```

Comment: UB and certainly doesn't work in constant expression context since `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed there at all.